# Is there an LED constant current driver that works like the UNL2003?

Tags: microcontroller, led-driver

I need a constant current driver that works like the UNL2003. Most of the LED constant currents drivers use serial communication with an MCU. Are there any ICs that might works like a ULN2003? (input wise)

edit - Well, there are actually some ICs that works like ULN2003 heck. Even better than that, it won't cost as many I/O pins as thevULN2003. They are generally called I/O expanders, a good example would be a TCA6408APWR. It can drive LEDs upto 25mA and uses I2C communication.

Comment: What is it about the ULN2003 that doesn't work for you?  (BTW - it's not clear why you call this a "constant current driver". That's not what a 2003 is.)

Comment: A ULN2003 plus a bunch of resistors?

Comment: I know what you are asking about, and I don't know of any offhand, and I don't think the market would be very big for them. A shift register, I2C or SPI is a lot simpler to interface with and requires fewer GPIO. If you do find one, it might not be available next week.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thanks! Understood. Could you recommend some chips you're mentioning other than TLC5947? i need it to work with Arduino so the input pins have to tolerate 5V. there is like, a lot of chips out there. i can't decide which one to select.

Comment: Eg.. ST STP08DP05MTR but better you search for yourself and find what looks good to you. Learn to use the parametric search function on Mouser and Digikey and you will benefit greatly.

Answer (score 2):

The ULN2003 is just a bunch of Darlington switches that depend on Vcc, collector R and load to limit the current.